# Bigquery API paging error

Tags: paging, google-bigquery

Today we started getting this errors when running queries that used to work fine. This happens when the nth page is requested. First page results work fine.

Is anyone else running through this issue?

Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[PROJECTID]/queries/job_ptZzrG-VPeOKW1Stac60vdLMpwQ?maxResults=1000&pageToken=CIDBB777777QOGQGBDIA6EHIA4%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D: (500) Backend Error

Comment: If you retry the same request, does it work? Or does it always give you the same error?

Comment: It does the same thing. I'm experiencing many weird behaviors with bigquery today. Im also having really stupid queries taking very long time to excecute, and some even failing. With "stupid" I mean queries that mysql without indexes would complete in a few seconds.

Comment: I've already reloaded the table with the same data, without any success. The table has a RECORD type field and some of the queries that fail may be related with "IS [NOT] NULL" comparison conditions. The error is always "Backend Error", same within API or bigquery.cloud.google.com. We'd really appreciate any help, we depend a lot in BQ.

Comment: Can you provide the project id?

Comment: It's 402341887237 and the affected table is [ta_data.total]. Today it works fine as if nothing had happen. Somehow this makes us doubt about when it's gonna fail again without knowing why :(